# Idea validation - CRF's as a service

Tags: ffmpeg, video-quality, h.264, h.265

I was looking for validation for my startup idea. Please flag if this is off-topic.

**Idea:** CRF's as a service - When encoding h.264 and libvpx videos, I tend to guess good Constant Rate Factors(CRF's) to make my videos smaller. I bet you guys experience the same. Instead of guessing, why not send the video to a dedicated 'crf-finder' then encode it later? The "crf-finder" would take a single video frame and find the best crf value.

**Questions**

1. Do you think this is dumb?
2. How much would you pay for this?
   This is my [landing page](https://phoneworker.online/). Perhaps you could look at it, subscribe to my mailing list or even try it out. I'm not charging - only trying to figure out if this is useful.

**This is what crf-finding looks like**
[image: phoneworker finding a crf]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to identify the CRF value that will either achieve a target file size or a target score on a quality metric like PSNR or VMAF.
However, a single frame is not enough to assess that.

The obtained average bit rate for a CRF encode of a file depends on the visual texture complexity and motion within *each scene*. So, you would need to process a set of representative range of frames from each scene. That doesn't fit with your proposal which appears to be a rapid assessment tool that looks at one frame (on a mobile device?).

There is an appreciable need for such a service, but it would run on the final encoding machine and examine the whole file, so probably a piece of software or script.

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate this.

Comment: Yes, it's rapid assessment on a mobile device. My target video consumer would be anyone watching a video on a mobile phone.